# Execute "executeAnonymous" from VF page

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, api, tooling

I have a VF page with Apex:InputText area and execute button. I want to execute tooling api **/executeAnonymous/?anonymousBody=**  from text area field and get the the result display in the VF page. I tried to use **@RestResource** and @HttpPost to achieve this. But no luck. Is there any other way i can do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Bear in mind that this is a hugely dangerous and insecure feature as Apex such as `delete [select Id from Account];` could be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="executeanonymous">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!textArea}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Click me!" action="{!submit}" />
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputText value="{!returned}" />
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class executeanonymous {
    public String textArea { get; set; }
    public String returned { get; set; }

    public void executeanonymous(){}

    public PageReference submit(){
        Http h = new Http();

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v35.0/tooling/executeAnonymous/?anonymousBody=' + textArea);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        returned = res.getBody();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It should display the result in a JSON string format. You'll have to mess with that to get your desired outcome :)